# How to set universal image loader to download a picture once?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm using universal image loader.
I want to download a picture from url and show it in my application.
I'm sure that i'll never change the picture in my site.
So I need it to be downloaded once. and don't even check the date of modification to download it. 

In fact I want the app to check if the image was downloaded the don't download it :)

How can I do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

instead of download image you should keep in `drawable` and use it
if you are download image via UID its save in catch memory and it is removable you can clear that catch once it is clear than you have to download again if you sure that you want download once only than i suggest go for `drawable` not for `UID` unless you have specific requirement

Comment: thank you @andruboy. But the there are lots of drawable. The user will choose some to view. The reason that forced me to do this is to decrease my sites traffic usage. There is no problem to redownload if user cleared data.

Answer (score 1):

On universal loader if you are true cacheInMemory then it maintain cache and your image download once. By default it is false:-

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        ...
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        ...
        .build();
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        ...
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
        ...
        .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

for more info you have to read below link:-

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader